# Issues with image banner with HTML5 CSS3 not expanding as parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

thanks for reading my question, I am working in a landing page that has a banner system, with css3 and html5 and jquery/javascript, I have been working for like 3 days now and I don't see the problem, the image is to short for the content/parent element, here is the webpage, so you can help me to figure it out what's happening.

http://topcoders.directoryup.com/landingpage/

HTML

```
<section class="city-section  
          first-city" 
          data-city="banner_0" data-bgColor="2">
            <div class="align-flex-end grid-flex-columns">

    <svg class="city-line new-york-line" viewBox="0 0 1911 1076" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
      <image class="bg" width="100%" height="100%" style="height:100% !important;width:100% !important;" xlink:href="images/2_a.jpg" overflow="visible"></image>
      <path data-offset="2871" data-rightLeft="M1939.9 478c-124.9-80.3-327.3 51.1-369.6 80.4-10.5 7.3-21.8 13.4-33.8 17.8-140.9 51.7-215.4-162.5-296.6-219.1-86-60-177 180.9-238 180.9-67.1 0-102.5-439.8-157.3-439.8-44.2 0-62.3 116.6-92.7 271.8-29.5 150.6-81.1 200.1-155.5 140.1-100.5-81-222.5 187.9-398.5 80.4-132.6-81-212-102.5-212-102.5" data-leftRight="M-14.1 488s79.4 21.5 212 102.5c176 107.5 298-161.4 398.5-80.4 74.4 60 126 10.5 155.5-140.1 30.4-155.2 48.5-271.8 92.7-271.8 54.8 0 90.2 439.8 157.3 439.8 61 0 152-240.9 238-180.9 81.2 56.6 155.7 270.8 296.6 219.1 12-4.4 23.3-10.5 33.8-17.8 42.3-29.3 244.7-160.7 369.6-80.4" d="M-14.1 488s79.4 21.5 212 102.5c176 107.5 298-161.4 398.5-80.4 74.4 60 126 10.5 155.5-140.1 30.4-155.2 48.5-271.8 92.7-271.8 54.8 0 90.2 439.8 157.3 439.8 61 0 152-240.9 238-180.9 81.2 56.6 155.7 270.8 296.6 219.1 12-4.4 23.3-10.5 33.8-17.8 42.3-29.3 244.7-160.7 369.6-80.4"></path>
    </svg>

    <div class="city-section-content grid">
        <div class="grid-cell">
          <h2>An eDirectory</h2>
          <p>An eDirectory</p>
            <a class="modal notified-modal no-url-update" data-remote="true" href="#">More Info</a>
        </div>
    </div>

  <span class="left-hitzone"></span>
  <span class="right-hitzone"></span>
</section>
                  <section class="city-section  
          " 
          data-city="banner_1" data-bgColor="1">
            <div class="align-flex-end grid-flex-columns">

    <svg class="city-line new-york-line" viewBox="0 0 1911 1076" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
      <image class="bg" width="100%" height="100%" style="height:100% !important;width:100% !important;" xlink:href="images/2_b.jpg" overflow="visible"></image>
      <path data-offset="2871" data-rightLeft="M1939.9 478c-124.9-80.3-327.3 51.1-369.6 80.4-10.5 7.3-21.8 13.4-33.8 17.8-140.9 51.7-215.4-162.5-296.6-219.1-86-60-177 180.9-238 180.9-67.1 0-102.5-439.8-157.3-439.8-44.2 0-62.3 116.6-92.7 271.8-29.5 150.6-81.1 200.1-155.5 140.1-100.5-81-222.5 187.9-398.5 80.4-132.6-81-212-102.5-212-102.5" data-leftRight="M-14.1 488s79.4 21.5 212 102.5c176 107.5 298-161.4 398.5-80.4 74.4 60 126 10.5 155.5-140.1 30.4-155.2 48.5-271.8 92.7-271.8 54.8 0 90.2 439.8 157.3 439.8 61 0 152-240.9 238-180.9 81.2 56.6 155.7 270.8 296.6 219.1 12-4.4 23.3-10.5 33.8-17.8 42.3-29.3 244.7-160.7 369.6-80.4" d="M-14.1 488s79.4 21.5 212 102.5c176 107.5 298-161.4 398.5-80.4 74.4 60 126 10.5 155.5-140.1 30.4-155.2 48.5-271.8 92.7-271.8 54.8 0 90.2 439.8 157.3 439.8 61 0 152-240.9 238-180.9 81.2 56.6 155.7 270.8 296.6 219.1 12-4.4 23.3-10.5 33.8-17.8 42.3-29.3 244.7-160.7 369.6-80.4"></path>
    </svg>

    <div class="city-section-content grid">
        <div class="grid-cell">
          <h2>A Responsive Website Creator</h2>
          <p>A Responsive Website Creator</p>
            <a class="modal notified-modal no-url-update" data-remote="true" href="#">More Info</a>
        </div>
    </div>

  <span class="left-hitzone"></span>
  <span class="right-hitzone"></span>
</section>
                  <section class="city-section  
          " 
          data-city="banner_2" data-bgColor="0">
            <div class="align-flex-end grid-flex-columns">

    <svg class="city-line new-york-line" viewBox="0 0 1911 1076" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice">
      <image class="bg" width="100%" height="100%" style="height:100% !important;width:100% !important;" xlink:href="images/2_c.jpg" overflow="visible"></image>
      <path data-offset="2871" data-rightLeft="M1939.9 478c-124.9-80.3-327.3 51.1-369.6 80.4-10.5 7.3-21.8 13.4-33.8 17.8-140.9 51.7-215.4-162.5-296.6-219.1-86-60-177 180.9-238 180.9-67.1 0-102.5-439.8-157.3-439.8-44.2 0-62.3 116.6-92.7 271.8-29.5 150.6-81.1 200.1-155.5 140.1-100.5-81-222.5 187.9-398.5 80.4-132.6-81-212-102.5-212-102.5" data-leftRight="M-14.1 488s79.4 21.5 212 102.5c176 107.5 298-161.4 398.5-80.4 74.4 60 126 10.5 155.5-140.1 30.4-155.2 48.5-271.8 92.7-271.8 54.8 0 90.2 439.8 157.3 439.8 61 0 152-240.9 238-180.9 81.2 56.6 155.7 270.8 296.6 219.1 12-4.4 23.3-10.5 33.8-17.8 42.3-29.3 244.7-160.7 369.6-80.4" d="M-14.1 488s79.4 21.5 212 102.5c176 107.5 298-161.4 398.5-80.4 74.4 60 126 10.5 155.5-140.1 30.4-155.2 48.5-271.8 92.7-271.8 54.8 0 90.2 439.8 157.3 439.8 61 0 152-240.9 238-180.9 81.2 56.6 155.7 270.8 296.6 219.1 12-4.4 23.3-10.5 33.8-17.8 42.3-29.3 244.7-160.7 369.6-80.4"></path>
    </svg>

    <div class="city-section-content grid">
        <div class="grid-cell">
          <h2>A Learning &amp; Workforce System</h2>
          <p>A Learning &amp; Workforce System</p>
            <a class="modal notified-modal no-url-update" data-remote="true" href="#">More Info</a>
        </div>
    </div>

  <span class="left-hitzone"></span>
  <span class="right-hitzone"></span>
</section>
```

UPDATE

when I use border:none anywhere the page breaks

[image: Broken style]

Comment: You'll have to show the code here. Else this question becomes useless once you fix the linked site.

Comment: @Shilly is a lot of code tos paste it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Required image size : **1911x1076** pixels
Please replace attached file with original file.
[image]

Comment: Is there a way to force the images to that size?

Comment: Yes after a lot of cropping, this was the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `border:none;` for section?  :)

Comment: It breaks all the site with border:none;

Comment: maybe sameting like that (only for active)? 
 .city-section.on {
    border: none;
}

Comment: The same, it breaks everything

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
.content-main-wrapper .city-section {
 border:none;
}
```

Comment: It breaks all the site with border:none;